# PHP. Передать в _POST и получить тип инпута

Tags: php

Передаю в _Post имя, значение и тип инпута:

```
$("form[name='inputData']").find("input:radio:checked,input[type=text],textarea,select").not('[type="submit"]').each(function() {
                    var name = $(this).attr('name');
                    var type = $(this).attr('type'); 
                    var value = $(this).val();
                    formData.push({
                        name: name, 
                        value: value,
                        type: type
                    });
                });
$.ajax({ 
                type: 'POST',  
                url: 'score.php',
                dataType: "html",
                data: formData,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#outputData').html(response);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        $('#outputData').html("<div class=\"error\">Извините, возникла непредвиденная ошибка</div>");
                    }
            });
```

Никак не получается из _Post получить type.
Так удается получить только имя и значение:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $name) {
        echo "$key".'='."$name".'&';
    }
```

Как правильно организовать цикл по _Post?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А что в $arr? Вы в него передали массив $_POST?

Comment: Да. В $arr был передан массив $_POST.

Comment: а делали var_dump($arr) чтобы понять что `type` вообще записывается в массив $_POST?

Comment: Делал. Типа там нет (array(12) { ["NPERS"]=> string(0) "" ["FAM"]=> string(6) "фыв" ["IM"]=> string(6) "фыв" ["OT"]=> string(6) "фыв" ["DATAR"]=> string(0) "" ["RA"]=> string(2) "15" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "7" [3]=> string(2) "11" [4]=> string(2) "14" [5]=> string(2) "15" ["q6"]=> string(0) "" }). Хотя в консоле браузера он есть.

Comment: так type это тип инпута всего-лишь, а пост-запрос передает значения инпутов в привязке к имени.почитайте про метод POST.

Comment: то что вы хотите сделать делается с помощью jquery. ищите потом по значению атрибута `name` тип `input`.

Comment: Спасибо. Могли бы Вы дать пример, как это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

> ajax.data **Object** must be Key/Value pairs

data должен быть объектом, а у вас массив

```
var formData = {};
$("form[name='inputData']")
    .find("input:radio:checked,input[type=text],textarea,select")
    .not('[type="submit"]').each(function() {
         var name = $(this).attr('name');
         var type = $(this).attr('type'); 
         var value = $(this).val();

         formData[name] = {
             name: name, 
             value: value,
             type: type
         };
     });

// Отправка без изменений
```

в бэкенде:

```
$arr = $_POST;

foreach ($arr as $key => $arValue) {
    echo "$key".'='."{$arValue['name']}".'&'."{$arValue['value']}".'&'."{$arValue['type']}";
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!